# On Click events - Similar to "Show Numbers" in voice control

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

I am looking for a way to activate the functionality of Windows' voice control `show numbers`.

#### `Show numbers`:

On the voice command `show numbers`, all on-click events in the active number is displayed with a number. Saying this number than clicks the button.

#### Background:

It would be so much faster to use than to tab through the single events or clicking on it.

#### Idea:

Is there any way to activate this functionality via `CMD`? In this case, I could just have the command in a little batch file, put this batch file as first item in the taskbar would allow me to activate it with `Meta`+`1`.

Sadly any research has proven fruitless. I only found one forum in which someone had the same idea, but this was a forum corpse.

Comment: Howdy. Requests for 'Software that does "X"' are explicitly off-topic here at SU.  To keep your question open rewrite it to remove all requests for software, and instead focus it directly (and exclusively) on the problem you're trying to solve, including research you've already attempted.

Comment: Just checked again. Checked before I started and it says on the help page questions are okay about software. Nothing about don't ask for software on the "do not ask" page. Open-ended questions are not okay, which is why I don't ask for which software is best. Actually, it's just an emergency resort if there is no built-in. A quick help center search for "software" didn't bring anything else up that helped me to see your point. For my own research, well, very little useful information. The only reason to mention it is to say: "Hey I tried, don't hate me for asking."

Comment: @TheCommoner282 You must have missed [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic): "and it is not about … **asking for a product**, service or learning material **recommendation**"

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think that this applies to this question, but why argue lengthily here. I edited my question to comply with your and Techie007's understanding of this.

Comment: @TheCommoner282 It's the **Community understanding**. That's why it is **in the help file**.